# How to combine BottomAppBar + FAB with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

I want to use the `FloatingActionButton`, along with its behaviour when anchored on a BottomAppBar, on top of a BottomNavigationView.

I came up with a rather "hacky" trick to just place the `BottomNavigationView` on top of the BottomAppBar without providing a background thus making it transparent.

This seemed to work well at first sight but I found out that the fab button can only be clicked when touching the upper half of the button (So where there is no transparent `BottomNavigationView` on top).

[image: Screenshot]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bar" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any way of implementing this idea in which I can fully click on the `FloatingActionButton`?

Comment: why not have the same function get called when clicking the center bottom navigation view button that's getting called when clicking the fab icon?

Comment: Since the middle navigation item is invisble, this was a possible solution I thought of as well. The FAB is clickable/focusable so in the perfect scenario, I don't want a ripple effect on the button when clicked underneath it.

Comment: `BottomAppBar` is just a specialized `Toolbar`. Have you considered trying to add your own labeled buttons directly to that? Seems a little less hacky than overlaying a `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: The reason of this hacky approach is to keep the behaviour of the FAB in the BottomAppBar. (E.G. animations). Perhaps someone has a useful solution for me, otherwise I should use my own button.

Comment: No, I mean, keep the `BottomAppBar` (along with its `FloatingActionButton`), and add buttons to it, instead of overlaying the `BottomNavigationView`. It shouldn't affect the FAB.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't following the guide here https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#anatomy ?

Comment: @ZUNJAE Yes, I want to have a navigation menu with items including icon+title.

Comment: How can you handle the FAB actions like the other items on the bottom nav ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> First Way

Try this You can Create a **`CustomBottomNavigationView`**

Here is the good article for `CustomBottomNavigationView`

[**How I draw custom shapes in BottomNavigationView**](https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView {

    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    /** the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button */
    private final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 128 / 2;
    // the coordinates of the first curve
    private Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();

    //the coordinates of the second curve
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    private int mNavigationBarWidth;
    private int mNavigationBarHeight;

    public CustomBottomNavigationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.colorAccent));
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Now use like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <neel.com.demo.CustomBottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/customBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomBottomNavigationView curvedBottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.customBottomBar);
        curvedBottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT

[image]

> Second Way

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: @CasparGeerlings welcome let me know if any help required

Comment: @NileshRathod I found that the "Second way", is probably the closest thing to what I was hoping for. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I tried the first way it worked and I want to have just one item on either side of the fab, how do I do that

Comment: @NileshRathod some space is left before the first textView in BottomAppBar in the second method, please can you help removing it?

Comment: for the second solution, anyone know how the textview can be styled so it can be displayed as active when clicked?

Comment: Hey!
first ones working, but I cannot open the link you provided. SO how do you resize the curves in case of the first one? I mean how do you know how big the fab will be?

Comment: How can you handle the FAB actions like the other items on the bottom nav ?

Comment: How can we do this in **Xamarin Forms** application? I didn't know whether it is possible or not without using any 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 29):

There is an easier way to combine those 3 widgets. We could have something like:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_activity_home_bottom_navigation" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And that's it.

Depending on where the FAB is anchored (CENTER|END) the menu icons will be placed either to the left or in the middle:

For this sample, the result would be something like:
[image]

If you think there's a better way, please feel free to edit/comment so I can fix the post :)

Comment: It doesn't work when the FAB is anchored in the CENTER.

Comment: @Shefchenko it works fine with center mode. Just use ```app:fabAlignmentMode="center"```

Comment: @Shefchenko To work in the middle just add `app:fabAlignmentMode="center"` as GrafOrlov said and remove also the `android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on API 21, on my phone running the latest version of Android works perfectly, but running it in an emulator on API 21 shows the BottomAppBar twice as big and the BottomNavigationView stays pinned at the top as if it had a margin_bottom

Comment: How can you handle the FAB actions like the other items on the bottom nav ?

Answer (score 8):

I found a quicker solution. I wrapped bottomnavigationview in frameLayout and everything work as expected. Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lt_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">


    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            style="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />


    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, especially when adding a FAB with the BottomAppBar. Was trying to fix this for the past few hours, thank you!

Comment: What kind of styles you define in BottomNavigationStyle             style="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"

Comment: How can you handle the FAB actions like the other items on the bottom nav ?

Answer (score 5):

To all who use second approach from [Nilesh Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865195/13070134) and want remove unexpected space before first text view:

Just set `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` for `BottomAppBar`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this for several days and in the end I came to make a FAB with an empty `BottomAppBar`, on top of which a `BottomNavigationView` with a transparent background was superimposed.

In my case, the code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGray"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#80FFFFFF"
            android:icon="@drawable/bottom_nav_ic_assignment"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onFabClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlue"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can treat BottomAppBar as Toolbar, which means that, this class extends ViewGroup so you can add relative layout, constraint layout etc inside BottomAppBar tag. Here is fragment of code that will show 2 buttons inside BottomAppBar.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:text="LEFT"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightbutton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rightbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="RIGHT"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftbutton"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```