# How to create BottomNavigationView with FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview, android-design-library, android-bottomappbar

I want to add Fab button to BottomNavigationView as Image below

[image]

How this can be achieved using BottomNavigationView or I will have to use BottomAppBar. How it can be achieved using BottomAppBar.

I found this library https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View but I want to know if this can be achieved without using library.

Comment: It's similar to curved Bottom Navigation View.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865195/7666442