# How to make curve line in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried with a shape, but I could not put the shadow or affected, I currently have a PNG but I have problems to accommodate the correct circle, so that it looks good on different screen sizes

There is some way to generate the curve and manage to leave the circle up and fit all mobile screens.

[image]

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864534/how-to-combine-bottomappbar-fab-with-bottomnavigationview/53865195#53865195

Comment: Google's Material Components library supports such layout. 
[https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/).

If it doesn't suits your case, try to draw on your own [see here](https://buptfarmer.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/bezier-curves-in-android-using-path-cubicto/). It is not very hard to do this.