# how to add a bottom app bar and menu in android?

Tags: android, menu, android-bottomappbar

I want to add menu bottom of activity.I can't add menu items,how can i add menu in bottom app bar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<include
        android:id="@+id/include"
         layout="@layout/appbar"/>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_marginTop="548dp"
      android:backgroundTint="#ffffff">
     </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
     </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: refer this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864534/how-to-combine-bottomappbar-fab-with-bottomnavigationview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine BottomAppBar + FAB with BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864534/how-to-combine-bottomappbar-fab-with-bottomnavigationview)

Comment: No.that isn't my answer.